# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::createTemporaryTable() in Magento

Tags: magento

I am downgrading Magento from EE to CE. I didn't do any important modification about code. I found this error after one night when I want to click "save and continue edit" of product today. Actually, the error was not the one in the title, it was "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::dropTemporaryTable()". And I found an answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11363/call-to-undefined-method-magento-db-adapter-pdo-mysqldroptemporarytable. I followed answer inside, and the error in the title occurred. Then I can't find any related answer.

Is there anyone can help? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that the Magento CE used for the downgrade was not the one the Enterprise version in use was built upon.